When and how the multivariate normal was defined using the Mahalanobis distance?
Actually, the title says it all. While the multivariate normal distribution has its roots in the era of Gauss, the Mahalanobis distance, introduced in 1936, provides a very nice way to define it, as it consist a natural generalization of the quantity $(x - m)/2s^2$.
When and in what context was the multivariate normal distribution formally expressed using this distance?

I am not sure what "formally expressed" means exactly but Mahalanobis's original paper, On the Generalised Distance in Statistics, already features multivariate normal distribution.

Indeed it is. Thank you for suggesting the article. I would be glad to accept the comment as an answer.
